# Quadrotor: Structure sensor compatible with gmapping

Tags: ros, quadcopter, navigation, gmapping, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Should I make any changes when using the gmapping_slam with structure sensor as it is not a laser scanner. I was told that odometry with SLAM yields accurate results.

Will the usage of gmapping_slam with structure sensor lead to overloading problems in the ODROID-U3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195488/quadrotor:-structure-sensor-compatible-with-gmapping/) by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're operating in a 2D environment (i.e. inside) you can convert your point clouds to laser scans using the [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) node. Then gmapping_slam will subscribe to the `scan` topic and it will work just the same as if a lidar was publishing it.

As for computational load, I've read about some people using the kinect with the ODROID-U3 for some tasks successfully, so I think it would be worth a shot for you to try it out to see if you can run all this on it, you might have some luck.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-21**:
Thanks

1. What kind of a map can I view in Rviz using the Structure sensor
2. How my I avoid obstacles using the sensor.? Should I use ultrasonic sensors or will the post SLAM process take care of it?
3. How is navigation made possible?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-10-22**:\

1. You can either view the point cloud, or the `scan` (the output of pointcloud_to_laserscan) in Rviz.

For the other questions, you might want to skim through the navigation [documention](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) and [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials) if you haven't yet.

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-22**:
So I should install the navigation stack along with gmapping_slam

what about avoiding obstacles

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-10-23**:
Yes the common practice is to use gmapping to create the map that the rest of the navigation stack uses for localizaiton. This process is discussed in the tutorials. Also, if you use the navigation stack, it handles obstacle avoidance automatically using a local map.

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-23**:
Will I need ultrasonic sensors for ceiling, floor estimation and obstacle avoidance

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-10-23**:
Are you using a UAV? If you're a ground vehicle you won't need to know where the ceiling and ground is (the ground is alway in the same place.)

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-23**:
Hi

I am using the Parrot AR.Drone with PX4 autopilot
I am using the [Structure Sensor](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/occipital/structure-sensor-capture-the-world-in-3d) for SLAM and I am sure that it will localize but will the map produced be able to avoid obstacles in all directions.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-10-23**:
Oh I see. Yeah I'm not sure then. You'll need to analysis the feild of view of the sensor to ensure it is adequate to capture the floor and ceiling for your application. Seems doable though.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-10-23**:
All my replies were assuming you were using a ground robot. You might want to edit your question a bit saying you're using that sensor on a UAV. I'm not even sure the navigation stack and gmapping play well with UAVs.

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-23**:
Hi

The FOV is Horizontal: 58°, Vertical: 45°

But I did come across a project where the gmapping was used with a quadrotor
[link text](http://www.aerialroboticscompetition.org/2012SymposiumPapers/2012IIT_Mandi.pdf)
[link text](http://people.csail.mit.edu/prentice/papers/jfr11-mav.pdf)